# Why is my react-native-copilot tour not starting on mount?

Tags: react-native

Whenever I try to start the tour from useEffect(), It does'nt work even if am passing setTimeout to it.
Example code is given below:

```
const tour = useCopilot();
useEffect(()=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
        tour.start("repaircat");
    }, 600)
},[]);
```

In the first screen I have started the tour by passing start() to the button click but in the second screen I want to initiate the tour again by calling start with the name of step through useEffect.

Is there any way to start the tour without clicking any button?

Comment: Using onLayout on the parent container is one of the solutions for autostart on mount: https://github.com/mohebifar/react-native-copilot/issues/287

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the tour isn't starting in your useEffect hook because the component or the tour content isn't fully rendered/initialized when you're trying to start the tour. One workaround for this issue can be using the useLayoutEffect hook instead of useEffect. The useLayoutEffect hook runs synchronously immediately after React has performed all DOM mutations, which can ensure that your component and the tour content are fully ready before the tour starts so use useLayoutEffect instead of useEffect and try it